# How do I stack multiple helper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, methods, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this bit of code:

```
@products = Product.order(id: :desc, :limit => 7)
```

Which returns the following error:

```
Direction should be :asc or :desc
```

It does work, however, if I set only one of those limiters. So what's the correct way of adding more than one helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
@products = Product.order(id: :desc).limit(7)
```